# How to exclude web app traffic from GA sales website view

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web application and a sales website residing on different domains and with unique Google Analytics properties. I would like to create a view of the sales website property which excludes all sessions/users accessing the web application.

I had hoped I could simply exclude users accessing the web application property from the sales website view using Google Analytics filters but that doesn't seem possible.

The alternative might be to use custom dimensions to record a common unique identifier when a client is using the web application so that I can exclude those same users from this new view of my sales website traffic.

The intent is to be able to have a view excluding all existing customers in Google Analytics without having to merge the properties.

Comment: Maybe you can just use segments to have one segment of sessions or users who didn't visit your application and sessions users who did? You can also use segments in conjunction with the custom dimension idea as well. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en

Comment: Actually, looks like they're on separate properties. I don't think this is only possible if you can somehow identify the client on both sites.

Comment: Yea the only solution I can think of right now is to write a cookie on app.domain.com which can be read by www.domain.com and use that to pass a custom metric to GA on www.domain.com.

Comment: The issue comes when someone arrives at your site on the sales side before the application side.

Comment: I can live with that I think, if I set a long life time cookie from the app then over time this will become less of an issue.